# Get Token Error in Gmail javascript API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to send mail through the Gmail API using the JavaScript library. This is my angular controller. I am getting error as Get Token is undefined which is `getClientRequestHeaders()` function.

```
myApp.controller('SignInCtrl',['$scope','$cordovaSQLite','$ionicLoading','$state','$rootScope','$http', 
  function($scope, $cordovaSQLite,$ionicLoading,$state,$rootScope,$http) {

var CLIENT_ID = '741594492560-ipa5tg0pkls6ubn6h.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login','https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo'];

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        loadGmailApi();
    }
}

$scope.initializeGMailInterface = function() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        immediate: true
    }, handleAuthResult);
};

function loadGmailApi() {
    gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', function() {
        console.log("Loaded GMail API");
    });
}

$scope.sendEmail = function() {
    var content     = 'HELLO';
    // I have an email account on GMail.  Lets call it 'theSenderEmail@gmail.com'
    var sender      = 'hello@hello.co.in';
    // And an email account on Hotmail.  Lets call it 'theReceiverEmail@gmail.com'\
    // Note: I tried several 'receiver' email accounts, including one on GMail.  None received the email.
    var receiver    = 'hello@hello.com';
    var to          = 'To: '   +receiver;
    var from        = 'From: ' +sender;
    var subject     = 'Subject: ' +'HELLO TEST';
    var contentType = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    var mime        = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';

    var message = "";
    message +=   to             +"\r\n";
    message +=   from           +"\r\n";
    message +=   subject        +"\r\n";
    message +=   contentType    +"\r\n";
    message +=   mime           +"\r\n";
    message +=    "\r\n"        + content;

    sendMessage(message, receiver, sender);
};

function sendMessage(message, receiver, sender) {
    var headers = getClientRequestHeaders();
    var path = "gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?key=" + CLIENT_ID;
    var base64EncodedEmail = btoa(message).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
    gapi.client.request({
        path: path,
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        body: {
            'raw': base64EncodedEmail
        }
    }).then(function (response) {

    });
}

var t = null;
function getClientRequestHeaders() {
    if(!t) t = gapi.auth.getToken();
    gapi.auth.setToken({token: t['access_token']});
    var a = "Bearer " + t["access_token"];
    return {
        "Authorization": a,
        "X-JavaScript-User-Agent": "Google APIs Explorer"
    };
}



}])
```

Comment: To start with I can tell you that Key != client id,   key is used for accessing pubic apis which gmail isn't so key wont work.  client id identifies your application and will not give you access to a users gmail account.   You will need to use Oauth2 to retrieve an access token then send access_token instead.  however the client library should be handling that for you so I am unsure why you are coding this yourself.  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js

Comment: thanks for the answer.i just want to send a mail from my controller. I found the code fro internet and used it. if u have anything regrading this me suggest me or help me with the code.

Comment: The link I posted is Googles official gmail quick start its the best place to start imo.

Comment: There is no message, receiver, sender. how to integrate that. As i am new to this please can u help me with code that a mail is to be delivered with message, receiver, sender and using my client ID.i dont want any login page just a button to send some predefined text to a mail.

Comment: Gmail accesses private user data there for you must be authenticated to access a users GMail account you will always need a login page.  There is no work around for that.  And as JavaScript is client sided you will not get a refresh token that you could use at a later date.    Consider using servicer sided language for this.